# How to enable spring security session management for specific url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a scenario where I have to implement Spring Security to secure a new endpoint among already existing other endpoints.

My configuration currently is as follows:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf().requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new CsrfRequestMatcher())
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession")
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/expiredSession").and()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/manage/*").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/user/login").permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/manage")
            .and()
        .logout().permitAll();
}
```

My requirement is to enforce the above spring security configurations for the /user/manage/* paths only. However, I notice that other mvc endpoints in my application cause a redirect to the /invalidSessions URL.

I want the other endpoints to work as they are and completely disable Spring Security for these endpoints (along with session management directives). The only place I know to do this is in the other configure override provided, but it doesn't exactly have what I need:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/cof/manage/*"); //need something like NOT "/cof/manage/*"
}
```

The ignoring above can be done on a per url basis, but not possible to disable to all URLs except a given URL. Is my only option to list down all the MVC endpoints that currently exist in my application except the "/cof/manage/*" path?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit misworded, as you don't want to disable only session management but spring security completely for specific URLs (disabling only session management is not possible per se; it would require to configure separate `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters` for the different URLs.

As you already said, it is however possible to completely disable spring security for URLs, and that is also possible with an exclusion with a `NegatedRequestMatcher`:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().requestMatchers(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/cof/manage/*")));
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the information. I didnt know that existed. However, I got my scenario to work in a different method. Simply started with `http.antMatcher("/cof/manage/**")` in the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method so the whole configuration applies only to the above path